# Is CE marking necessary for product used by myself?

Tags: european-union, consumer-protection

I have made a device to take and print pictures during parties and social meetings, as part of my job (party organizer).

If I sell this device, it would fall under "*Low Voltage Electronic Device*" and would require CE-marking.

But I'm not selling it, just using it myself during the parties I'm organizing to take pictures of people attending.
Is CE-marking necessary for such a use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using something you've made and not placing it "on the market", you do not appear to be a "manufacturer" as defined in paragraph 3.1 of [2016/C 272/01](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=OJ:C:2016:272:FULL&from=EN).

> "The manufacturer is any natural or legal person who manufactures a
>   product or has a product designed or manufactured, and places it on
>   the market under his own name or trademark."

That said, it's worth considering that the places you use your equipment may have other requirements, particularly if you are offering a service for payment. [Portable Appliance Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_appliance_testing) is likely to apply for UK venues, and venues in other EU nations may have similar requirements.